# Create a new single dimensional array by matching each value of a single-dimensional array with "name" key of a nested multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is the multi-dimensional nested array called `multi`:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4d4b7104d754a06370d81259
            [name] => Arts & Entertainment
            [pluralName] => Arts & Entertainment
            [shortName] => Arts & Entertainment
            [icon] => Array
                (
                    [prefix] => https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/default_
                    [suffix] => .png
                )

            [categories] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 56aa371be4b08b9a8d5734db
                            [name] => Amphitheater
                            [pluralName] => Amphitheaters
                            [shortName] => Amphitheater
                            [icon] => Array
                                (
                                    [prefix] => https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/default_
                                    [suffix] => .png
                                )

                            [categories] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4bf58dd8d48988d1f8931735
                                            [name] => Bed & Breakfast
                                            [pluralName] => Bed & Breakfasts
                                            [shortName] => B & B
                                            [icon] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [prefix] => https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/travel/bedandbreakfast_
                                                    [suffix] => .png
                                                )

                                            [categories] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4f4530a74b9074f6e4fb0100
                                            [name] => Boarding House
                                            [pluralName] => Boarding Houses
                                            [shortName] => Boarding
                                            [icon] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [prefix] => https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/travel/hotel_
                                                    [suffix] => .png
                                                )

                                            [categories] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4fceea171983d5d06c3e9823
                            [name] => Aquarium
                            [pluralName] => Aquariums
                            [shortName] => Aquarium
                            [icon] => Array
                                (
                                    [prefix] => https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/aquarium_
                                    [suffix] => .png
                                )

                            [categories] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4d4b7105d754a06372d81259
            [name] => College & University
            [pluralName] => Colleges & Universities
            [shortName] => College & Education
            [icon] => Array
                (
                    [prefix] => https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/education/default_
                    [suffix] => .png
                )

            [categories] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4bf58dd8d48988d198941735
                            [name] => College Academic Building
                            [pluralName] => College Academic Buildings
                            [shortName] => Academic Building
                            [icon] => Array
                                (
                                    [prefix] => https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/education/academicbuilding_
                                    [suffix] => .png
                                )

                            [categories] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4bf58dd8d48988d199941735
                                            [name] => College Arts Building
                                            [pluralName] => College Arts Buildings
                                            [shortName] => Arts
                                            [icon] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [prefix] => https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/default_
                                                    [suffix] => .png
                                                )

                                            [categories] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4bf58dd8d48988d197941735
                            [name] => College Administrative Building
                            [pluralName] => College Administrative Buildings
                            [shortName] => Administrative Building
                            [icon] => Array
                                (
                                    [prefix] => https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/education/administrativebuilding_
                                    [suffix] => .png
                                )

                            [categories] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )
       )
)
```

This is the single dimensional array called `single`:-

```
array(
  [0] => 'Aquarium',
  [1] => 'Amphitheater'
)
```

I want to create a function which would iterate though the multidimesional array recursively and when the value of `single` will match "name" key of `multi`, a new array will be formed which will contain "id" and "name" of each node that matches with `single`.

How can I do it?

Here is what I tried to do, but somehow can't figure out how to make the recursive call:-

```
public static function array_flatten($fs_array, $cat_array) { 
        if (!is_array($fs_array)) { 
            return FALSE; 
        } 
        $result = array(); 
        foreach ($fs_array as $key => $value) 
        { 
            if(in_array($value['name'], $cat_array))
                    $result[] = $value['id']; 
        } 
        return $result; 
}
```

Comment: To make a recusive call, your function should focus on the 'categories' element of your object, this is the recursive part in your data. If your function focusses at this, it can then call itself when the name does not match with the 'categories' value of the current object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I build a solution based on your example. I didn't test it, but the idea behind it is:

You check if there is a "categories" key which is an array and if so takes that subarray and passes it into flatten_array again. The return value of the recursive call will afterwards be merged into the $result array.

```
public static function array_flatten($fs_array, $cat_array) { 
        if (!is_array($fs_array)) { 
            return FALSE;
        } 
        $result = array(); 
        foreach ($fs_array as $key => $value) 
        { 
            if(in_array($value['name'], $cat_array)) {
                $result[] = $value['id'];
            }
            // ----- here starts what I added -----------
            if (is_array($value['categories'])) {
                $result = array_merge($result, self::array_flatten($value['categories'], $cat_array));
            }
            // ----- here ends what I added -----------
        } 
        return $result; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a little error I think. The second `if statement` should be outside the first one, otherwise the recursive call will not take place when the first `name` doesn't match.